# How to send multiple parts of the single data which are generated at different intervals over TCP?

Tags: networking, tcp

I have a problem where my data source is generating parts of the data in delayed intervals and I want send these data parts over TCP and make sure all the parts are received at once?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all data pieces received at once on the destination then you need to send them that way - queue them locally and send when complete.